# <img> and background-image size is different

Tags: html, css

Why is it that when I set both the `<img>`'s width and height to 400px, the image is exactly square, but when I use a `<div>` to then apply a `background-image` to it and set the same size there, the picture is disproportionate, and only if I set `width: 1600px` and `height: 400px`, then it becomes square?

How to set the `background-image` size correctly so it becomes square, just as `<img>`?

I added this to background image, but it didn't work:

```css
background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
width: 400px;
height: 400px;
```

Here's my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vwe6hsn9/6/ (try to comment out the width & height, the image disappears).

I would also like to have a `background-color` in case the image won't load for the user, so that they know here should be a picture. But it's also not visible if you remove the image.

Comment: Isn't it something you can adjust with the background-size CSS property?
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size

Comment: Please share the actual code, this should be easy to pour into a snippet and show. Do you want the image to distort like with the img element?

Comment: @Mikou Oh, so I can set a width and height there. That's interesting. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: Remove `background-size: cover` and turn it into `background-size: 100% 100%` to stretch it like an image tag. You have specifically added CSS to get a different effect.

Comment: Thank you! It worked and I also think I still need`background-size: cover` besides `400px` to perfectly fit. I also wanted to add a placeholder in case the image won't load for the user. I always set `background-color` before the `background-image`. And if I use `background-size: 400px 400px;` only, the image is now square, but the background-color is stretched to full. The solution I found is to set `width: 400px` and `height: 400px` in addition to the `background-size: 400px 400px;`. But is there a shorter solution? If I find the solution to this, I'll close the question and post my answer.

Comment: You are asking very strange questions. If your box is `400x400` and `background-size` is `100% 100%`, it's the same as an image of `400x400` with _no_ additional CSS set. You can use `object-fit: cover` and `background-size: cover` to use the same effects. Also, you shouldn't see the background color in this case. I feel you are overcomplicating this.

Comment: As I said I need a background-color in case the image won't load for the user. So he can at least see a placeholder, so that he knows that here should be a picture.

Comment: @somethinghere Here's the example: https://jsfiddle.net/s5w2tumy/21/. Try to uncomment the width and height, and then try to uncomment the background-image: cover;. First of all, `background-size: 100% 100%` and `background-size: cover` are not the same.  `100%` = Fills the area but all of the image is visible, when `cover` = Scales the image to be large enough until the background area is completely covered by the image. The original Image size is `640x425`. I want it to be `400x400` and if I don't use height and width, but only background-size, I won't see the image at all.

Comment: Note: I never said `background-size: 100% 100%` and `background-size: cover` are the same, I said `object-fit: cover` for the `<img />` and `background-size: cover` for a background are. My issue is that you are combining a lot of varied CSS rules that have different effects for different reasons. You are overcomplicating this by trying to replicate one's behaviour in the other.

Comment: @somethinghere My 'overcomplicating' is called learning. I don't know how to solve my issue, that's why I'm trying different things and that's why I ask here on StackOverFlow. Yet the issue isn't solved. Instead, I receive 'you are asking very strange questions' which isn't that informative. Your solution didn't work. I posted a fiddle, if you can solve it - please give it a try.

Comment: When you remove the width and height of your div, it disappears because it is empty; it doesn't contain anything; it shrinks to a size of zero width and zero height. However, your question is unclear or you appear to be asking multiple questions at the same time. You'll get much clearer answers if you edit your question to make it clearer.

Comment: @Michael The issue is that you are mixing up a bunch of values, and the behaviours for both are different. You should remove all the CSS related to scaling and see how they act differently - backgrounds tend to just be printed as is, and cut off where the box ends, while images don't do that (as one would expect). You are overcimplicating because you are asking questions about multiple css values at the same time, all of them having different effects. So try to simplify before you make it more complicated, it will help learning a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. When we set `background-size: cover;` it instructs the browser to scale the background image while maintaining its aspect ratio to cover the entire container. This can result in the image not being displayed in its original dimensions, causing distortion.
2. As @Brett Donald mentioned, we can't just use `background-size: 400px 400px;` without adding a `width` and `height`, because

   > when you remove the width and height of your div, it disappears
   > because it is empty; it doesn't contain anything; it shrinks to a size
   > of zero width and zero height
3. Also, if you have any element (for example text) next to the element that contains a `background-image`, I'd suggest using `flex-shrink: 0;`, because is a way to prevent `background-image` from shrinking when its container is smaller than the  size of the `background-image`.

So, if we want the `background-image` to be `400x400` we can do the next:

```css
background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;  // or background-size: 100% 100%, depending on what you need.
width: 400px;
height: 400px;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try giving these values to the *img* style so it fills the entire screen:

```css
background-size: 400% 400%;
height: 100%;
margin: 0;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
```

Please note that if you want to use a background image try these instead:

```css
background-image: url('your-path');
background-size: 400% 400%;
height: 100%;
margin: 0;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-size: cover;
```

Comment: `background-size: 400% 400%;` makes my image too large. I need it to be `400px x 400px`, but if I remove the `height` and `width`, my image disappears, check it here - [link](http://jsfiddle.net/s5w2tumy/21). Try to uncomment the `width` and `height`.

Comment: Did you try to refactor ```background-size: 400% 400%``` to ```background-size: 400px 400px``` ?

Comment: Yes, look at my fiddle. You can replace 100% with 100px, you won't see the difference.